# VBA - path, GetSaveAsFileName gives URL / SaveCopyAs works with UNC

Tags: vba, url, sharepoint, path, unc

- GetSaveAsFileName gives an **URL** path;
- SaveCopyAs vould get an **UNC** path;
- The file is not saved;
- The prozess does not give a warning;
- The SharePoint access is not a mapped drive; **It has been mounted as a library.**
- I can not use a constant path because the user can choose an other sharepoint mappe.

This is my code:

```
  'Test: Is the file exists?

Dim CW_ExportFilePathAndName As String
CW_ExportFilePathAndName = FilePathForSave & CW_NameSaveFile
If Dir(CW_ExportFilePathAndName) <> "" Then
    Dim InitialName As String
    Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
    InitialName = CW_ExportFilePathAndName
    sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
        If sFileSaveName <> False Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs sFileSaveName
            MsgBox "The source file is saved on an individual name!"
        Else
            MsgBox "The source file is not saved!"
        End If
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs CW_ExportFilePathAndName
End If
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you are working with? It is difficult to help when we can't see what you are doing specifically, and what is going wrong. Also, how are you retrieving these prompts? Are you prompting the user for them?

Comment: `CW_ExportFilePathAndName = FilePathForSave & CW_NameSaveFile` this is what's giving you the URL, but your code doesn't show how `FilePathForSave` and `CW_NameSaveFile` are created

Comment: Hi, I've attached my code! I tested the path with msgbox. My path: "\\ecs.tel.de@DDA\RaWrote\sites\DKO\aaa.xls" The return value: "https:/ecs.tel.de/sites/DKO/aaa1.xls./"  If I good understand your second question: no, I aren't.  I have information about it.  Thank you! Bye, Z

Comment: Hi! My Path works! Good! Well, if the file does not exist, than the file will bee saved. If the file exists, than I ask the user, witch name... and the GetSaveAsFilename gives me the URL. It is correct, but the SaveCopyAs can not use it.

Comment: And: Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm") gives me an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: SaveAs can work with URL. Only the reopen must bee solved!